# Android retrieve data from php org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: php, android, json

I am try to get a group of data from php server to android.
but a error are occurred when I execute the project, try refer to several related questions however I still cant come up with a solution.

here is my asynctask which will establish connection and sent momentID to php

```
class GetAllComment extends AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<Comment>> {


    protected ArrayList<Comment> doInBackground(String... params) {
                    List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    int success;
        try {
            Log.d("","@@@### " + postedID);
            param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("momentid", postedID));
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    "http://192.168.168.111:80/testmoment/getallcomment.php", "GET", param);

            // check your log for json response
            Log.d("Single comments Details", json.toString());

            // json success tag
            success = json.getInt("success");
            if (success == 1) {

                JSONArray productObj = json
                        .getJSONArray("product"); // JSON Array


                try {
                    JSONObject comments = productObj.getJSONObject(0);
                    Comment comment = new Comment();
                    comment.setCommentContentbody(comments.getString("vcontentbody"));
                    comment.setCommentDate(comments.getString("vcdate"));
                    comment.setCommentTime(comments.getString("vctime"));
                    list.add(comment);

                    Log.d("","tryget : " + comments.getString("vcid") + " AND " + comments.getString("vcontentbody") + " AND " + comments.getString("vcdate") + " AND " + comments.getString("vctime"));

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } else {

            }
        }catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return list;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Comment> list) {
        cAdapter = new CommentAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), mCommentLists);
        commentList.setAdapter(cAdapter);
        mComment = new Comment();
        cAdapter.Update();

        if(list != null){
            for(Comment comment: list){
                cAdapter.add(comment);
            }
        }


        cAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

here is my php script :

```
<?php

header('Content-type: application/json');
include "db.config.php";
if (isset($_GET['momentid'])){
$momentid = $_GET['momentid'];
$result =mysql_query("SELECT * FROM commenttable WHERE vcmomentid = $momentid");

if (!empty($result)) {
    // check for empty result
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        $json_output[]=$row;

print(json_encode($json_output));

mysql_close();
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // no product found
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No product found";

        // echo no users JSON
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // no product found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No product found";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}

?>
```

here is the error I get once execute :

```
JSON Parser: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value [{"vcontentbody":"gkkgv","vcid":"1","vcmomentid":"109","vcdate":"2015-11-23","vcuserid":"1578","vctime":"17:09 PM"}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Please Help me find the error. Thanks

Comment: your data is retrieve in JSON Array type not JSON Object type. so get data in JSON Array not JSON Object

Comment: As in log `of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject`

Comment: Post your `Json` data.

Comment: edit the code please? I know my data are retrieve in JsonArray but not Jsonobject, but my problem is how to change the Jsonobject to JsonArray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you are getting `JSONArray` that you are converting to `JSONObject`

```
[ // This is Array
    { // This is Object
    "vcontentbody":"gkkgv",
    "vcid":"1",
    "vcmomentid":"109",
    "vcdate":"2015-11-23",
    "vcuserid":"1578",
    "vctime":"17:09 PM"
    }
]
```

So you have to write like:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest("http://192.168.168.111:80/testmoment/getallcomment.php", "GET", param);
```

Now check whether it is **null or not**

```
if(jsonArray != null)
{
    // Here You may not have any key like 'success' so i don't have taken.

    // You can directly get JSON Object here.. If you are getting more than one JSONObject then make loop here...
    JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

    // Now you can do with object that you want to do.
    Comment comment = new Comment();
    comment.setCommentContentbody(object.getString("vcontentbody"));
    comment.setCommentDate(object.getString("vcdate"));
    comment.setCommentTime(object.getString("vctime"));
    list.add(comment);
}
```

If any question, You can ping me. May it will helpful to you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code by which you can parse your data ,please put your jsonArray in response variable

```
try {
        JSONArray arr=new JSONArray(response);

        JSONObject jobj=new JSONObject(arr.get(0).toString());

        for(int i=0;i<jobj.length();i++)
        {
           Log.e("Index 0", ":"+jobj.getString("vcontentbody")) ;
           Log.e("Index 1", ":"+jobj.getString("vcid"));
           Log.e("Index 2", ":"+jobj.getString("vcmomentid")) ;
           Log.e("Index 3", ":"+jobj.getString("vcuserid")) ;
           Log.e("Index 4", ":"+jobj.getString("vcdate")) ;
           Log.e("Index 4", ":"+jobj.getString("vctime")) ;
        }


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: i am not good in parse the json i just want to ask you that you are using arr.get(0) what exactly is that

Comment: we are doing that for getting the first position

Comment: i am doing that for getting first array